# how can i execute a host class function in a CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, device, global

I have a genetic algorithm and i'm traying to evaluate a population of chromosome on GPU :

```
class chromosome
{
    int fitness; 
    int gene(int pos) { .... };
};

class eval
{
  public :    
  __global__ doEval(Chromosome *population)
 {
     ....
     int jobid = population[tid].gene(X);
     population[tid].fitness = Z;
     ....
 }
};

int main()
{
    Chromosome *dev_population;
    Eval eval;
    eval.doEval<<<1,N>>>(dev_population);
}
```

and i have this errors :

```
ga3.cu(121): warning: inline qualifier ignored for "global" function
ga3.cu(121): error: illegal combination of memory qualifiers
ga3.cu(323): error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function
ga3.cu(398): warning: nested comment is not allowed
```

where are the problems ?

i remove Eval class and left only doEval function , and make *device* *host* gene() , like this :

```
\__device\__ \__host\__ gene()
{....};


 \__global\__ doEval(Chromosome *population)

 {
     ....
     int jobid = population[tid].gene(X);
     population[tid].fitness = Z;
     ....
 }

int main()
{
    Chromosome *dev_population;
    doEval<<<1,N>>>(dev_population);
}
```

but now i have have other errors , and it's not compile :

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip(66): error: expected an expression

/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip(96): error: expected an expression

/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip(127): error: expected an expression

/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip(195): error: expected an expression

/usr/include/c++/4.6/iomanip(225): error: expected an expression

5 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00006fe9_00000000-4_ga3.cpp1.ii".
```

Comment: Perhaps this is wrong, but does it fix the problem to declare `int gene()` as inline, or add the __device__ tag to it?

Comment: effectively for gene function adding _device_ _host_ solve the problem , but the big one is the class function call

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems here, one soluble, the other one not.

1. It is illegal in CUDA for a `__global__` function (ie. kernel) to be defined as a class member function. So `doEval` can never be defined as a member of `eval`. You are free to call a kernel in a structure or class member function, but a kernel cannot be a member function. You will have to redesign this class, there is no work around.
2. Any function called device code must be explicitly denoted as a device function and be instantiated and compiled for the device. This applies to both regular functions and class member functions. All functions are treated by nvcc as host functions unless identified as otherwise. You can, therefore, fix this error by doing something like the following:

```
class chromosome
{
    int fitness;

    __device__ __host__ int gene(int pos) { .... };
};
```

Note that every function called by `gene` must also have a valid device definition for the code to successfully compile.

Comment: @user3083350: If this answer solved your problem, I would appreciated it if you could accept it. This will get the answer off the unaswered question list for the CUDA tag and make the question and answer more visible in search for the next person that comes along with the same question.